# Gráfico com Seaborn com um dos eixos sendo o index

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

Estou com um dataframe, o mesmo possui um index padrão, porém susbtituir esse index padrão pelo nome dos  estados brasileiros e agora gostaria de plotar uma bar plot vertical, utilizando o Eixo Y com o nome dos estado (valores  do index) e o eixo X como um valor de mortes por estado. Porém o seaborn está me retornando um erro que não estou conseguindo interpretar.

[image: Dataframe]

[image: Código do Seaborn]

[image: Erro retornado]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passei pela mesma situação hoje e consegui resolver desta forma.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
sns.barplot(data=df, x='mortes_confirmadas', y=df.index)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Felipe, o método barplot não consegue interpretar 'covid_By_state.index' pois seu dataFrame não possui nenhuma coluna com este nome. Crie uma coluna com outro nome (state, por exemplo) e alimente ela com os estados que estão indexando seu dataFrame. Isso deve resolver.

Aqui está um exemplo parecido onde plotei os dados por região.

```
fig3, ax3 = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(10,6))
sns.barplot(data=pd.DataFrame({
    'TotalCasos':maxByReg,
    'Região':aadf.Região.unique()}),
     x='Região',y='Total Casos',palette='rainbow')
ax3.set_xlabel('Região ',size='x-large')
ax3.set_ylabel('Total de casos (30-03)', size='x-large')
```

Só uma dica: tente compartilhar conosco seus datasets e seus códigos. Screen shots não facilitam muito o trabalho que tem está interessato em ajudar.

[image: exemplo]

Espero que tenha conseguido resolver o seu problema, abraço.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta camarada!